# How to get dst start time and end time using tz database in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, dst

I am trying to extract dst's (daylight saving time) start time and end time from tz database. (under /usr/share/zoneinfo/...)

There are some methods to get it such as below.

1. strings /usr/share/zoneinfo/EET
2. zdump -v EET

But, the methods above are based on shell.

Is there any API to extract dst start,end time in C/C++ using tz database?